# How to compile a static FFmpeg binary on OS X

Tags: macos, compilation, ffmpeg

I want to compile a static ffmpeg binary by myself. I follow [this guide](https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/MacOSX), and then built one successfully.

```
./configure --extra-version=Chitanda_Eru --prefix=/Volumes/Chitanda_Eru/ --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-pthreads --enable-avisynth --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libbluray --enable-libtheora --enable-libcelt --enable-openssl --enable-libspeex --enable-postproc --enable-libvpx --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-fontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libass --enable-filters --disable-indev=qtkit --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libtwolame --enable-openal --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwavpack --enable-libvidstab --enable-libilbc --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libcaca --enable-opengl --enable-frei0r --enable-libquvi
```

But I come across a problem, the FFmpeg binary is only 15.5MB which is much smaller than the official builds, what's more, it can't work on my second Mac and with errors below.

```
Library not loaded: /usr/local/lib/libx264.142.dylib
  Referenced from: /Applications/CLI/ffmpeg
  Reason: image not found
Trace/BPT trap: 5
```

And then I use otool command to see what the dynamic libraries ffmpeg rely on.

```
otool -L /Applications/CLI/ffmpeg | grep local

    /usr/local/lib/libSDL-1.2.0.dylib (compatibility version 12.0.0, current version 12.4.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libx265.25.dylib (compatibility version 25.0.0, current version 1.2.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libx264.142.dylib (compatibility version 0.0.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libvorbisenc.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.10.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libvorbis.0.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.7.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libogg.0.dylib (compatibility version 9.0.0, current version 9.2.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libvo-aacenc.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.3.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libvidstab.0.9.dylib (compatibility version 0.9.0, current version 0.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libtheoraenc.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.2.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libtheoradec.1.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.4.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libspeex.1.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libquvi.7.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.1.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libopus.0.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libopenjpeg.1.dylib (compatibility version 7.0.0, current version 7.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencore-amrwb.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.3.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libopencore-amrnb.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.3.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libmp3lame.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libgsm.1.0.13.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.13)
    /usr/local/lib/libfreetype.6.dylib (compatibility version 18.0.0, current version 18.2.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libfontconfig.1.dylib (compatibility version 10.0.0, current version 10.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libfdk-aac.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.4.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libfaac.0.0.0.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libcaca.0.dylib (compatibility version 100.0.0, current version 100.19.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libcelt0.2.dylib (compatibility version 3.0.0, current version 3.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libbluray.1.dylib (compatibility version 8.0.0, current version 8.0.0)
    /usr/local/lib/libass.5.dylib (compatibility version 6.0.0, current version 6.0.0)
```

Most of my packages are installed by Homebrew, and Homebrew will install them with "--enable-static --enable-shared". And my guess is: when I compile ffmpeg, ffmpeg rather use the dynamic libraries than the static libraries, so the binary won't work on other Macs.How can I build a static binary of ffmpeg? Thanks.

update: I successfully build static ffmpeg after moving all the dylibs which have static libraries as well to other dictionary and disable all the libraries that ./configure can't find.

```
./configure --extra-version=Chitanda_Eru --prefix=/Volumes/Chitanda_Eru/ --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --enable-nonfree --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-ffplay --disable-ffserver --enable-pthreads --enable-avisynth --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libfaac --enable-libfdk-aac --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-libtheora --enable-libcelt --enable-openssl --enable-libspeex --enable-postproc --enable-libvpx --enable-libgsm --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-filters --disable-indev=qtkit --enable-runtime-cpudetect --enable-bzlib --enable-zlib --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libtwolame --enable-libsoxr --enable-libwavpack --enable-libilbc --enable-opengl --enable-frei0r
```

Comment: Which `./configure` command did you use when you compiled it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will make a difference, although you might try adding `pkg_config='pkg-config --static'` toward the beginning of part of your `./configure` command, and perhaps using `--enable-static` after `--enable-libx264` instead of before it.

It looks as if you have the libraries in the right place, although your prefix directory should normally be `/usr/local`. Another thing you could try is to update the dynamic shared library install name with `install_name_tool`, which might solve the problem.

After the build is finished use:

```
install_name_tool -id $PREFIX/lib/libx264.142.dylib libx264.142.dylib
```

This updates the `rpaths` recorded in a Mach-O binary.

Comment: Thanks very much and it can be better if there's a solution to include the static libraries right in the binary.BTW,personally,For smaller file size-->libx265, for larger size and higher quality-->libx264. x265 can't retain detail,will cause color banding and often crashes, so I seldom use it. And ffmpeg binary included libfaac or fdkaac is nowhere to download(for the nonfree license), so I have to compile one myself.

Comment: I added another suggestion to the answer `pkg_config='pkg-config --static'`. If I come across something else I'll definitely let you know.

Comment: I've compiled one with the option just now, but ffmpeg still uses dylibs.

Comment: @Chitanda_Eru, Do you have `pkg-config` and `glib` installed on your machine? Both are required in order to compile libs into the binary. You might want to post your updated `./configure` command also.

Comment: yes,I have. I've updated post, by moving dylibs to other path and disabling some libraries I build the static one. Thanks for your help.

Comment: "unless there's some compelling reason to use both" x265 builds HEVC files where x264 builds AVC files. If I'm not mistaken those are two completely separate encoders for two separate codecs (even if they are closely related).

Comment: @l'L'l I don't see where, unless you're referring to Chitanda_Eru's first comment which suggests that the two are interchangeable except for a quality/size tradeoff.